# How to retrieve map object by passing it to model

Tags: java, oop, dictionary

I have a map object where data is retrieved using key value. Is there a way to pass this mapping object to model to retrieve it's values.

This is mainly for code reusability.

```
UserViewModel decrypteduser = DataEncryptionUtil.decrypt(user);
```

and then to retrieve:

```
decrypteduser.getEmail(), decrypteduser.getFirstName()
```

But how can I do this in

```
for(Map<String, Object> resultMap : resultSet) {
                Map<String , Object> map  = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("userId", (Long)resultMap.get("USER_ID"));
    map.put("userName", DataEncryptionUtil.decrypt((String)resultMap.get("USER_NAME")));
    map.put("firstName", DataEncryptionUtil.decrypt((String)resultMap.get("FIRST_NAME")));
    map.put("lastName", DataEncryptionUtil.decrypt((String)resultMap.get("LAST_NAME")));
                                adminUsersList.add(map);
}
```

Please help me with this as I am new to java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson library to convert Map to Object

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // jackson's objectmapper
UserViewModel decrypteduser = mapper.convertValue(map, UserViewModel.class);
```

Also, if it is possible to edit the above mentioned for loop, directly set the values in User object instead of storing it in `map`

Comment: where could i pass object data to DataEncryptionUtil.decrypt(); to decrpt